# How can I find if somebody access the database and changes a record?

Tags: sql-server

How can I find out if somebody access the database and changed a record value.

is there any query can tell me.

For Example,

Let us say that we have a table called products that has 3 columns .

Here is a sample records.

```
ID      Name     Status
1       A        1
2       A        0
```

So my logic will check when inserting the values. If there is a record in the DB for Product A as Status 1, Do not Insert it again.

However my table suddenly got this logic

```
  ID      Name     Status
    1       A        1
    2       A        1
```

Is their any SQL Query that can tell me if somebody run this script in my DB:

```
Update Products
SET Status 1 WHERE ID =2
```

Comment: I assume you don't have any logging on your database? If knowing who is changing rows, and when, is important in your application then you need to design  your application(s)/database(s) to store that information.

Comment: I stored that Information, however I have some constrain in my data, and suddenly I got some records violating the rules. So I was wondering that somebody who has access to the database run an update query and modify the last modified by to somebody else.

Comment: So, if you are logging the actions of your users, the information of "who did what" will be in there, will it not?

Comment: Yes. But the application logic will not allow such change, however it happened ?

Comment: I don't know your application, and can't see what you do. You understand your application, and your logs, so you *should* be able to derive what occurred from those; either by looking at the actions the users did, and the changes to the data, etc. You can then talk to the user that the logs said made the changes; perhaps they can then shed light on what they did and may well have found a "flaw" in your application that allows them to do something you thought not possible

Comment: If you would like to handle this better next time, you might want to consider adding audit triggers (On Insert, On Update, On Delete). I use them to get a copy of the data before changes, and the name of the user who is making the change. I store it in a table somewhere else (so the bandit doesn't hide his tracks).